# How to pay to a customer using quickbooks API?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

The QuickBooks API provides an API (https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/payments/charges) to accept payments from a customer using a credit card. But how can we pay back a customer? Is there any payment API where I can send money to my customer? Is it possible?

> --New Edit--

Example scenario: I have 2 layers of customers, level one customers have to receive payments from level2 customers. The process goes like this, level2 customers will pay me and I will transfer to the level1 customer. Of course, I will take a small commission amount. The refund will not help here ??? I am looking for something like payout (is payout available ???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBooks Payments does not support `pay-outs`. If you're looking for payouts, look elsewhere.

You can issue a REFUND with the `Refund a charge` endpoint:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/payments/charges

e.g.:

```
POST /quickbooks/v4/payments/charges/<id>/refunds
Content type: application/json

{
  "id": "",
  "created": "",
  "amount": 5.00,
  "context": {
    "tax": 0,
    "deviceInfo": {
      "id": "",
      "type": "",
      "longitude": "",
      "latitude": "",
      "phoneNumber": "",
      "macAddress": "",
      "ipAddress": ""
    },
    "recurring": false
  },
  "description": "first refund"
}
```

Which returns something like:

```
{
  "created": "2014-09-23T01:49:12Z",
  "amount": "5.00",
  "description": "first refund",
  "id": "EMU891209421",
  "context": {
    "tax": "0.00",
    "recurring": false,
    "deviceInfo": {
      "id": "",
      "type": "",
      "longitude": "",
      "latitude": "",
      "phoneNumber": "",
      "macAddress": "",
      "ipAddress": ""
    }
  }
}
```

You can't just send random dollar amounts to customers. (They wouldn't be "customers" if you were just sending them money -- the definition of a "customer" is someone you are taking money FROM, not giving money TO.)

Comment: I have 2 layers of customers, level one customers have to receive payments from level2 customers. The process goes like this, level2 customers will pay me and I will transfer to the level1 customer. Of course, it will take a small commission amount. The refund will not help here ??? It is like payout (is payout avaible ???). Updated the question also

Comment: Intuit Payments does not support payouts. Added clarification to my answer about what is and isn't supported.